# How to access IPv6 websites via the mobile network

Tags: ipv6

my landline only has an IPv6 address (well in addition IPv4 via crappy DSLite). I'm anyway trying to set up an owncloud server at home and access it from remote locations. So the task by now is to access the owncloud server via IPv6 using my Android 5.0.0 phone (Moto G 2014).

If I open the IPv6 address in my browser on the phone while connected to the same WiFi as the owncloud server everything works fine. But once I turn off WiFi and switch to cellular data the server can't be accessed anymore even though my router is configured to pass every connection to the owncloud servers IPv6 address range. This result is still reasonable since via the mobile network I only have an IPv4 address and no IPv6 address, so I can't communicate directly with an IPv6 target.

Are there some tricks to still reach an IPv6 host through an IPv4 connection on Android? Using tunnels ect? Or is this completely impossible by design?

Thanks a lot for replys!

Answer (score 1):

You can only reach IPv6 sites from your device if it has IPv6 connectivity, whether it be via an IPv6-enabled WiFi network or via your mobile carrier's network. It is not generally possible to reach IPv6 sites if you only have IPv4 connectivity.

#### The below is no longer relevant because SixXS is now defunct. Thanks to [Rodney](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/118297/rodney) for the tip-off.

<s>You can set up an IPv6 tunnel for the times when you are on a network that doesn't provide native IPv6. I was able to find two Android apps which set up tunnels to the free [SixXS](https://www.sixxs.net/main/) network:</s>

- The [Androiccu](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.web_troubles.androiccu) app is based on the aiccu program for PCs that sets up [SixXS](https://www.sixxs.net/main/) tunnels. It claims to require a rooted phone.
- [IPv6Droid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.flyingsnail.ipv6droid) claims to be able to do the same, without requiring the phone to be rooted.

I've used SixXS and aiccu since 2006 and they are generally quite good, though their [points of presence](https://www.sixxs.net/pops/) can go offline or be decommissioned without notice.

I haven't tested either app, as I've had native IPv6 at home for a few months and on my mobile for a couple of years now. Given that I know in general how tunnels are set up, I would expect the app requiring a rooted device to be more reliable, and if you are rooted, I would start with that one.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, Dan: Michaels hint still sort of works. You can still use [IPv6Droid](https://flyingsnail.de) (even from [Sources](https://github.com/pelzvieh/IPv6Droid/tree/1.0_Maintainance)) today either

1. using the built-in tunnel subscription for its own tunnel infrastructure for a monthly fee, or
2. setting up [IPv6server](https://github.com/pelzvieh/IPv6DroidServer) by yourself, requiring a site that is accessible via static IPv4 address as well as via a static IPv6 address block: this might be at your favourite VM hoster or perhaps even your home server if your landline happens to meet these criteria.